# ASP.net inner join not supported error

Tags: sql, join

From what I've looked up this should be working. Why it is not is something I need help with. Would removing the AS statements do any good?

```
SELECT td.Title, ti.Path, td.ImageID, ti.ImageID, td.Description 
FROM TravelImage as ti 
Inner JOIN TravelImageDetails as td ON (ti.ImageID=td.ImageID) 
AND Title LIKE '%" + @query + "%' OR Description LIKE '%" + @query + "%'
```

EDIT: the error that I'm getting is that it says the join is not supported

Comment: You haven't described in what way it's not working. You should also *definitely* be using parameterized SQL.

Comment: your query seems ok to me. what is it showing now?

Comment: posting your error would help us to understand and give us a chance to help you better/faster

Comment: @user1834616 What database do you use? Also, the parameter name had very questionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query,
i think **where** condition is missing ?

```
SELECT  td.Title, ti.Path, td.ImageID, ti.ImageID AS Expr1, td.Description
    FROM  TravelImage AS ti INNER JOIN
    TravelImageDetails AS td ON ti.ImageID = td.ImageID 
    Where  Title LIKE '%" + @query + "%' OR Description LIKE '%" + @query + "%'
```

Comment: Nailed it. Working perfectly now, I'd up-vote you if I could.